# How to get the exact location of text occurred in a PDF using ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, pdf, search, search-engine

I am building an application that needs to have the function to allow users to search similar contents within a pdf(probably using ElasticSearch)... As I did write some code to find out how to find that exact pdf file using ElasticSearch but I have no idea how to get the exact location of the text... Or how can I highlight the search results? It would be really helpful if code examples are provided >_<

Answer (score 1):

**You can use [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html) where highlighters enable you to get highlighted snippets from one or more fields in your search results so you can show users where the query matches are.**

Adding a working example with index data,search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "content": "The nonprofit Wikimedia Foundation provides the essential infrastructure for free knowledge. We host Wikipedia, the free online encyclopedia, created, edited, and verified by volunteers around the world, as well as many other vital community projects. All of which is made possible thanks to donations from individuals like you. We welcome anyone who shares our vision to join us in collecting and sharing knowledge that fully represents human diversity."
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content": "online"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "content": {}
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65463291",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "content": "The nonprofit Wikimedia Foundation provides the essential infrastructure for free knowledge. We host Wikipedia, the free online encyclopedia, created, edited, and verified by volunteers around the world, as well as many other vital community projects. All of which is made possible thanks to donations from individuals like you. We welcome anyone who shares our vision to join us in collecting and sharing knowledge that fully represents human diversity."
        },
        "highlight": {                      // note this
          "content": [
            "We host Wikipedia, the free <em>online</em> encyclopedia, created, edited, and verified by volunteers around the"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: That's an awesome comment. Thank you so much. However, this method seems not working with pdf...? My pdf is base64 encoded and ElasticSearch did not return the highlighted pdf... Instead, it has returned highlighted text...

Comment: @水野しろ thanks for the reply :) You need to install a plugin that will index a pdf document and make it searchable and then you can use the highlighting query, to highlight the matched text. You can refer to this blog https://qbox.io/blog/powerful-pdf-search-elasticsearch-mapper-attachment/ and https://qbox.io/blog/how-to-index-attachments-and-files-to-elasticsearch-5-0-using-ingest-api

Comment: Thank you. The tutorial is helpful but a little bit outdated... I still have some problems with the mapping of my pdf files. Could you please give me a little more information on how to create the mapping for my pdf files? The sample files are stored in Onedrive if you wouldn't mind having a look at these files. Thank you again for your help, sincerely. I really appreciate it. The link is: https://80gtoy98tstcjsado2ubiyrz0nt-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/mashiro_od_renhui_tk/ErrV9SOQkE1GkDJT3OWBvccB6G1fYiIHeFJVk3HZ2Ay3vw?e=Hfm9Zz